# QuerySelector of LWC Tree Grid Row

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I'd like to change the background color of a specific row in a tree grid, but how can I select the row?

My current attempt fails as there is never a value assigned to `row`.

```
renderedCallback() {
  const row = this.template.querySelector('[data-row-key-value="ROW_KEY"]');
  if (row) {
    console.log('row found');
    row.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }
}
```

Here is the template

```
<template>
  <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
    <template if:true={gridData}>
      <lightning-tree-grid
        columns={gridColumns}
        data={gridData}
        key-field="Id"
        is-loading={isLoading}
        hide-checkbox-column=true
        ontoggle={handleRowToggle}
        expanded-rows={currentExpanded}
        show-row-number-column=true
      >
      </lightning-tree-grid>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: not enough info for us to help, what does your template look like? are you using a namespaced component?

Comment: @glls I've added the template. It's not namespaced.

Comment: lightning-tree-grid is a lightning namespaced component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom) is a standard that encapsulates the internal document
> object model (DOM) structure of a web component. Encapsulating the DOM
> gives developers the ability to share a component and protect the
> component from being manipulated by arbitrary HTML, CSS, and
> JavaScript. The internal DOM structure is called the shadow tree. The
> shadow tree affects how you work with CSS, events, and the DOM.

Component's DOM elements & CSS are isolated to its own, meaning you can't modify it from outside. So what you're trying to do is security feature & designed this way.

### Recommended

So the straightforward & legit answer to your question is you can't do this & should roll your own tree-grid component & you can styling it the way you want. You can utilize the template provided [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tree-grid/) & add functionality to it.

### SUBJECT TO CHANGE

Salesforce doesn't recommend doing it this way & is subject to change. This may fail in future SF release if they modify the internal which you targetted from the static resource. So use it on **YOUR OWN RISK**.
The other way to style these component would be through a static resource which applies to the document level. You can write the same style in .css file upload it as static resource & load it in your lwc.

customTreeGrid.css

```
tr[data-row-key-value="ROW_KEY"]{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

customLwc.html

```
<template>
  <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
    <template if:true={gridData}>
      <lightning-tree-grid
        columns={gridColumns}
        data={gridData}
        key-field="Id"
        is-loading={isLoading}
        hide-checkbox-column=true
        ontoggle={handleRowToggle}
        expanded-rows={currentExpanded}
        show-row-number-column=true
      >
      </lightning-tree-grid>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

customLwc.js

```
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformLoader';
import  CUSTOM_STYLES from 'lightning/resourceUrl/customTreeGrid';
export default class CustomLwc extends LightninEl....{
   isLoaded = !1;
   async renderedCallback(){
      if(!this.isLoaded){
       await loadStyle(this, CUSTOM_STYLES);
       this.isLoaded = !0;
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't peer past the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom), so you're only allowed to style the "outside" of the component. You won't be able to affect elements inside the tree either by CSS or by JS, except as outlined in [Styling Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/). You'd need to make your own component, instead.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I decided to highlight the target row by simply selecting it. The implementation of this component already hides checkboxes from the user, so this was a very simple way to identify the row. Unfortunately, there are no styling hooks for changing the selection color, so I also added an icon.

[image]

```
// component.html
<template>
  <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
    <template if:true={gridData}>
      <lightning-tree-grid
        columns={gridColumns}
        data={gridData}
        key-field="Id"
        is-loading={isLoading}
        hide-checkbox-column=true
        ontoggle={handleRowToggle}
        expanded-rows={currentExpanded}
        show-row-number-column=true
      >
      </lightning-tree-grid>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

// component.js (edited for brevity)
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import getInitialData from '@salesforce/apex/ComponentController.getInitialData';
import getChildRecords from '@salesforce/apex/ComponentController.getChildRecords';

export default class Component extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  isLoading = false;
  selectedRow = [];
  @track gridData;
  @track gridColumns = [
    {
      type: 'url',
      fieldName: 'url',
      label: 'Name',
      typeAttributes: {
        label: { fieldName: 'Name' },
        tooltip: { fieldName: 'Name' },
      },
      cellAttributes: {
        iconName: { fieldName: 'isCurrentAccount' },
        iconPosition: 'right',
        iconAlternativeText: 'Current Account',
      },
    },
    // other columns
];

  connectedCallback() {
    this.fetchRecords(this.recordId, true);
  }

  fetchRecords(parentRecordId, onLoad = false) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.getData(onLoad)({
      recordId: parentRecordId,
    })
    .then((serverData) => {
      if (serverData) {
        const newGridData = serverData.map(record => this.buildTreeNode(record));

        if (onLoad) {
          this.gridData = newGridData;
          this.selectedRow = [this.recordId]; // SELECT THE TARGET RECORD HERE
        } else {
          // async loading of nested records
        }

        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // handle errors
    });
  }

  buildTreeNode(element) {
    let record = element.record;

    // SPECIFY THE ICON VALUE HERE
    if (record.Id === this.recordId) {
      record.isCurrentAccount = 'utility:success';
    }

    // other stuff, mostly related to the nested _children

    return record;
  }

  // the rest, unrelated to this question
}
```